# Proving that if a family of sets $\cal{A} \ne \emptyset$ is totally ordered with respect to $\subseteq$ then $\bigcap\cal{A} \in \cal{A}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Assume that $\mathcal{A} \neq \emptyset$ is an arbitrary family of subsets of $X$, such that $(\mathcal{A}, \subseteq)$ is a total ordering.
I want to prove that the intersection of all members of $\mathcal{A}$ is also a member of $\mathcal{A}$; i.e that $\bigcap\mathcal{A} \in \mathcal{A}$.

For all finite $\mathcal{A}$ this can be done by induction.
Note that for all $A,B \in \bigcap{A}$, $A \subseteq B$ and $A \cap B = A$, or $B \subseteq A$ and $A \cap B = B$; in any case, $(A \cap B) \in \mathcal{A}$.
Base case: $\bigcap\{A\} = A$ and $A \in \{A\}$.
Inductive step: assume true for all families of cardinality $n  \in \mathbb{N} \ge 1$.
Given $|\mathcal{A}| = n + 1$ let $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{A} \setminus \{A\}$ for some $A \in \mathcal{A}$; then $|\mathcal{B}| = n$, so $\bigcap\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{B}$ and thus $\bigcap\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{A}$.
Consequently $\bigcap\mathcal{A} = A \cap (\bigcap\mathcal{B}) \in \mathcal{A}$.

Now I'm trying to prove it for all infinite $\mathcal{A}$ too.
I've tried to prove it directly, contrapositively, and by contradiction (assuming $\bigcap\mathcal{A} \notin \mathcal{A}$), but I am stuck.
Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the family of non-empty open intervals $(0,a)$ has an empty intersection, which is not a member of the family. @HagenvonEitzen I just noticed and edited :)

Comment: Very easy to understand counter-example, thank you. But could the statement at least be proven for countably infinite families, or is it false for those too?

Comment: @bkalmar Let $a$ be restricted to positive rational numbers, and the same example works.

Comment: Or take intervals $(n,\infty)$. This is all related to order-completeness, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(order_theory) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been pointed out in the comments that the statement is not generally true for infinite families, and so cannot be proven.

Comment: Including countably infinite families, as noted in the comments....+1